# Django - FilePathField returns wrong paths

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I'm trying to allow admin to choose from flags when they creates neww `Language` object.

There is a folder `mainapp/static/img/flags/550px/` with `*.png` images of flags.

```
class Language(models.Model):
    shortcut = models.CharField(max_length=40,
                                help_text=_('Shortcut of the language'),
                                unique=True)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=40,
                            help_text=_('Name of the language'),
                            unique=True, verbose_name=_("Language"))

    flag = models.FilePathField(path='mainapp/static/img/flags/550px'),default='/static/img/icons/check-icon.png')
    #flag = models.FilePathField(path='{}\mainapp/static/img/flags/550px'.format(settings.BASE_DIR),default='/static/img/icons/check-icon.png')
```

The problem is that Django doesn't resolve those paths in html. There are paths like this: `mainapp/static/img/flags/550px\es.png` which is a problem because Django starts in `/static/`, not `/mainapp/`.

On the other hand, when I put `static/img/flags/550px`, it does not let me choose from the folder.

So the main problem is that when admin choose from flags, it saves path with `mainapp/static..` at the beginning. I want to save only `static/..`

Do you know what should I do?

Comment: once check your static,static root setting in settings.py.

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify [STATIC_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_URL), [STATICFILES_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS)?

Try to add this to your project settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ('PATH_TO_STATIC',)
```

Answer (score 0):

In settings do

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = ['path/to/mainapp/static']
```